# VBA - Closing the Opened form by DblClick Event, closes the whole running code?

Tags: vba, excel, class, userform

I have a userform and some textboxes, I created a `DblClick` event to open and fill the second form according to the text box data. The problem is when I close Userform4, the whole running forms disappear! Nothing happens when I close userform3. But still, the mouse pointer shows the round status, like it is running a code!
I tried to change the `Query_Close` event of the second form to hide, but no luck. Can you please help? There is no Cancel button the Second form.

```
Private Sub txt1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If Txt1.Locked = True Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("target").Range("a1")
        UserForm4.TextBoxJob2 = Txt1.value
        UserForm4.TextBoxBadgeNum2 = .Offset(RowNumber, 3)
        UserForm4.ComboBoxAC2 = .Offset(RowNumber, 0)
        UserForm4.Show
    End With
Else
    UserForm3.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Regards,
M

Comment: on the closing of `UserForm4.Close` ?

Comment: yes, when I click on the Query_close of this form. Not on the other form of userform3.

Comment: It's a bit difficult, as you don't provide much background on how this is put together, nor repro steps. But... While VBA lets you work with a form as your code shows, the more reliable way to avoid "odd things" is to declare an object as a specific UserForm (which is, under the covers, a Class), instnatiate a new instance and then `.Show` that. Example: `Dim frm As frmTest : Set frm = New frmTest : frm.Show : Set frm = Nothing`

Comment: Thanks As I checked on other computers, there was not such an error and also now on my own computer!! So strange.